ancho en flexbox
No sé como hacer para que los items que están dentro del main no se deformen y tengan un valor mínimo para poder encojerse en el eje x.
La imagen está al límite antes de pasar al siguiente media Query. Para diseños utilizando grid podemos utilizar por ejemeplo
width: minmax(200px, 1fr)

pero no he logrado dar con un atributo para logar algo similar utilizando flexbox

